# get out data from promise function in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I have this service file part of angular project , issue is I cant back value to main function from promise.then function .. here is the code

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])

.factory('Services', function ($http,$q) {

    var def = $q.defer();
  // Might use a resource here that returns a JSON array
    $http.get('JSONFILE').then(function (data) {
        def.resolve(data.data);
    });


this.result ={};
    var var1 = def.promise;
            var1.then(function (data){
                this.result = data;
                console.log(this.result);
            });

    // Some fake testing data
  console.log(this.result);

        return {
            all: function () {
                return var1;
            },
            remove: function (service) {
                var1.splice(var1.indexOf(service), 1);
            },
            get: function (serviceId) {
                for (var i = 0; i < var1.length; i++) {
                    if (var1[i].id === parseInt(serviceId)) {
                        return var1[i];
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
        };

});
```

this.result will return empty object outside promise.then but get right data inside it.

Comment: 1. `this` inside the `then` function will not be the `this` you think it is. 2. your usage of `var1` in the `return`ed object is completely invalid, extensive rewrite is required

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you are talking about this log statement here:

```
// Some fake testing data
console.log(this.result);
```

The reason why `this.result` doesn't have the same data is because the `Promise` is probably still pending (fulfilling the promise).

I suspect when you see these `console` logs, you see the one *outside* the Promise display first. This is to be expected.

---

Also, your block scope is different, meaning `this.result` can be different inside that Promise context.

Try changing:

```
this.result = {};
```

to:

```
var result = {};
```

And also change

```
var1.then(function (data){
    result = data;
    console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: it not about console.log(this.result). It's about moving data from inside promise.then to factory function.

Comment: the console.log however illustrates the problem

Comment: Yes as mentioned it just reveals the issue in terms of the program flow. I updated to address some other issues that may occur depending on your block scoping.

Comment: I'm sorry but I try this before this.result . it give me same result .